# What is causing "Javascript error (unexpected token)" in this code snippet?

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I am trying to push weather data into Google Analytics. (I am following a tutorial online; I am not proficient in Javascript but I know Python.) I have set up datalayer variables, tags and triggers, but I have a custom HTML tag that calls Openweathermap API, and pushes all this data to the datalayer, so my tag can then take this information and fire back to Google Analytics.

Could someone please have a look at this code and tell me why I get a "Unexpected Token on Line 28 ({)" error?

```html
<script>
(function() {

  var fetchWeatherData = function(longitude, latitude) {
    // Open Weather Map
    var owmAppKey = '<baeb0853a54bef1870ecdd0345bb0f5e>';
    jQuery.getJSON('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=' + latitude + '&lon=' + longitude + '&units=metric&APPID=' + owmAppKey)
      .done(function(data) { 
        window.dataLayer.push({
          event: 'weatherDone',
          weather: data.weather[0].main,
          temperature: data.main.temp.toFixed(0) + ' °C'
        });
      }).fail(function(jq, status, msg) {
        console.log('Weather request failed: ' + status + ' - ' + msg);
      });
  };   

  var geoLocateUser = function() {
    $.getJSON('//extreme-ip-lookup.com/json/')
        .done(function(data) { 
          fetchWeatherData(data.lon, data.lat);
        }).fail(function(status, msg) {
          console.log('IP request failed: ' + status + ' - ' + msg);
        });
  };
  
  if (typeof {{Session alive}} === 'undefined') {
    geoLocateUser();
  }

  // Reset "session" cookie with a 30-minute expiration
  var d = new Date();
  d.setTime(d.getTime()+1800000);
  var expires = "expires="+d.toGMTString();
  document.cookie = "session=1; "+expires+"; path=/";

})();

</script>
```

I am guessing this is a really basic Syntax error that is easy to fix, but I am not proficient with Javascript and cannot figure this out.

Many thanks!

Comment: I've *no* idea what `typeof {{Session alive}}` is supposed to be doing

Answer (score 0):

A few things:
You're getting an error because `typeof {{...}}` is improper syntax.
Also, `Session alive` isn't anything. If it's a variable it should be one word like `Session_alive` or `Session-alive` or `sessionAlive`.
Also, double curly braces `{{...}}`(moustache template) are usually used in some JS frameworks but are not a feature of vanilla JS.
Single curly braces indicate an object (ex: `{a: 'one', b: 'two'}`.
If `sessionAlive` was a variable of some kind and you wished to verify if it was an object you'd write `typeof sessionAlive`.
But if you're checking to see if the value `Session` is `alive` then you'd write a conditional such as `if (Session === 'alive') ...`,
or check if `Session` is undefined such as `if (Session === undefined) ...`

Comment: {{Session Alive}} is a datalayer variable set up in Google Tag Manager; as far as I am aware this is the correct syntax for a datalayer variable in GTM.

Comment: Interesting.
Even if that's the case, using the syntax `if (typeof {{Session alive}} === 'undefined')`
does not make sense. 
Maybe `if (!{{Session alive}})` to check for falsiness?

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the "Session alive" tag is properly set up in Google Tag Manager?